# Check if $Cov(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2)=0$, i.e. if independent?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance

"Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent, $N(0,1)$-distributed random variables. Show that $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ are independent."

I know that for multivariate normal distributions *independence can be proven if the covariance equals zero*. So if I let $Y_1=X_1+X_2$ and $Y_2=X_1-X_2$, then:

$$
Cov(Y_1,Y_2)=E[(Y_1-\mu_1)(Y_2-\mu_2)],
$$
where
$$
\mu_1=E[Y_1]=E[X_1+X_2]=EX_1+EX_2=0+0=0
$$
and
$$
\mu_2=E[Y_1]=E[X_1-X_2]=EX_1-EX_2=0-0=0.
$$
Thus we get that
$$
Cov(Y_1,Y_2)=E[(Y_1-0)(Y_2-0)]=E[Y_1 \cdot Y_2]=
$$
$$
=\int \int y_1 y_2 \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac {-y_1^2} 2} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac {-y_2^2} 2} dy_1dy_2
$$
Now this is where I get lost. I am not sure about what limits I am supposed to be interating over? Can anyone please explain how I am supposed to think here? Thanks

(I already know that the answer is going to be $Cov(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2)=0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Cov$ has all the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties) of an inner product. So, instead of trying to calculate this expected value explicitly, use these properties
\begin{align}Cov(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2)&=Cov(X_1,X_1)-Cov(X_1,X_2)+Cov(X_2,X_1)-Cov(X_2,X_2)\\[0.2cm]&=σ^2_{Χ_1}-Cov(X_1,X_2)+Cov(X_1,X_2)-σ^2_{X_2}\\[0.2cm]&=1-1=0\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, Just what I had missed! Do you think there will ever be a scenario where I will need to integrate as above (If X1 and X2 are still indpt)?

Comment: It may happen. But before you integrate, apply these properties first. This will simplify things for sure. In most cases it will suffice.

Comment: Ok, thanks Stef!